# How to change the jupyter favicon.ico

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking for to customize the a jupyter notebook.

How to change the jupyter notebook favicon.ico[1] ?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

step 1: download a local copy of [jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook)

step 2: change favicon located at `notebook/static/base/images/favicon.ico`

step 3: install this version using `python setup.py install`

Comment: I should have expected a less invasive way ;(

Answer (score 4):

The proper elegant way to *override* the existing default favicon, without rewriting it is to create a `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` file with the following content:

```
requirejs([
    'jquery',
    'base/js/utils',
], function($, utils
    ){

    utils.change_favicon("custom/favicon.ico")
});
```

Place your custom favicon.ico to the same folder.

There is a [doc page](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.html) that does not provide a solution, but talks about `custom.js` mechanism in general.

Answer (score 2):

You already have a local copy of jupyter, you just need to dig for it. If you use conda in your root environment it is here:

```
$ ~/miniconda/lib/python*/site-packages/notebook/static/base/images/favicon.ico
```

For a particular environment it is here:

```
$ ~/miniconda/envs/<env_name>/lib/python*/site-packages/notebook/static/base/images/favicon.ico
```

Once you change the favicon you don't need to reinstall jupyter, just refresh the browser window and it should change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick bash script that overrides arbitrary `.ico` files in the `notebook` directory local `.ico` files of the same name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Just switches ipython notebook favicons out
# User array notation to expand pattern
base=~/anaconda3
icodir=($base/lib/python*/site-packages/notebook/static/base/images)
icofiles=($icodir/*.ico)
icofiles=(${icofiles[@]##*/})
[ ! -d "$icodir" ] && echo "Error: Directory not found: \"$icodir\"." && exit 1

# Move the custom favicons
dir=~/bin/favicons # override
files=($dir/*.ico)
files=(${files[@]##*/})
for file in ${files[@]##*/}; do
  if [[ " ${icofiles[@]} " =~ " $file " ]]; then
    echo "Overriding favicon with file \"$file\"."
    so=$dir/$file    
    if [ ! -r $icodir/${file%.*}-default.ico ]; then # save old ones
      cp $icodir/$file $icodir/${file%.*}-default.ico
    fi
    cp $so $icodir/$file
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the working location of your **Jupyter notebook** by opening the console.

   [image: Getting location of Jupyter notebook]
2. Then you go to the {anaconda location}/lib/site-packages/notebook/static/base/images and overwrite the desired images. 
   [image]

**Note: Since browsers cache favicons, the effect may take sometime. You should test it by opening notebook in other browser.